# Is it Ok if i leave vertices alone?

Tags: modeling, materials, uv, vertices, subdivision-surface

I'm ongoing with my Private model again . This time it more complex and i'm adding some material in this work So here my problem

[image]

If i leave vertices like that just to keep the shape of the gun's curve , Will it be a problem when i subdivide model and add material and texture later ?

Comment: What do you mean by "alone"? Are you going to fill the holes with faces?

Comment: Yes it will probably be a problem with a subsurf. Try to get rid of them by connecting the last loop's vertices to an angle, trying to stick with 4 sides polygons as much as possible. Keep in mind that rendering with opengl uses triangles, always, to represent a mesh, for instance a square is vertices 0, 1, 2 (top, bottom, right) and 0, 2, 3.

Comment: I understand wanting to get a definitive answer on this, but couldn't you just add a subsurf and see the result yourself?

Comment: i already did that . it turn out ok but im not sure it will be stable when i adding material and rendering because this is a first time i will add material and texture in my 3d model